# Short description not updating

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

We have a data feed that populates our store with product data, and a short description for each product is provided as part of that. When I edit the short description, then 'save and continue' the record is saved but the short description has returned to the original text. This does not happen with any other attribute of the record. I can edit and save changes to the long description; I can even add a new attribute set and update the values in those fields.

I could only find one reference to this issue on the web and the proposed solution was emptying the cache and trying again. This did not work for me.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Thanks, Alistair.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a cache issue. Refresh all your caches.

If you have a CLI access:

Do the following from the CLI at the root of your magento install

```
    rm -rf var/cache/*
    php shell/cache.php --refresh all
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data feed could be importing an invalid character that's causing Magento to fail when it attempts to resave it. I've seen this when routines directly update mysql instead of using Magento objects to import data.  The data will display as it was imported but the save function causes an error that prevents the save from committing to the database.

In your import routine ensure that you are properly sanitizing your data. If you're importing with a direct mysql call for short description then consider changing to the Magento product object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Including the columns '_store' and '_product_websites' in the CSV upload with 'base' value for _product_websites.